# Adding picture to powerpoint slides via C# throws The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, office-automation

Hie guys,

I have a block of code here:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imageurl"].Value.ToString());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
string strImagePath = pptdirectoryPath + "\\" + currentSlide + "_" + shape.Id + ".png";
img.Save(strImagePath);
tempSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(strImagePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, shape.Left, shape.Top, Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgwidth"].Value), Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgheight"].Value));
shape.Delete();
```

`tempSlide.Shapes.AddPicture` works fine for smaller images,and it fails when resolution is higher(here fail means response is not received for infinite time and throws exception when page is refreshed).

**Exception Message:** The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes.AddPicture(String FileName, MsoTriState LinkToFile, MsoTriState SaveWithDocument, Single Left, Single Top, Single Width, Single Height).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also having trouble with this issue. I would like to know what your tempSlide object is? the AddPicture function seems to be adding the image to different locations on the page depending on the slide template. My tempslide object is             `PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            PowerPoint.SlideRange tempSlide = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;`

Comment: @user1: can you share how are you using the method??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue.used below code to addpicture

```
tempSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(strImagePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Convert.ToInt32(shape.Left), Convert.ToInt32(shape.Top), Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgwidth"].Value), Convert.ToInt32(xmlTempNode.Attributes["imgheight"].Value));//load new image to shape
```

The problem was, i was sending msoFalse for LinkToFile and msoTrue for SaveWithDocument.

and now ,passing msoTrue for LinkToFile and msoFalse for SaveWithDocument did my job.

happy Coding..